# What is the problem with my bump mapping?

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor

I am trying to map a high resolution bump map on a UV sphere, I am using a UV map, and I get this result:

[image: rendered moon]

What causes the renderer to make these huge blobs? This should be a moon, far away and big (distance is about 500, size is 300 blender units), my bump map is 3840 x 2160  Pixels TIF file (I got the same result with a half resolution bump map, too), UV-mapped to the sphere. Mesh is set to smooth, Subsurf is set to 4 subdivisions, and the node setup is as follows:

[image: Nodes]

Mapping (if I map the bump map to the color of the diffuse shader, it does not get pixelated):
[image: UV Mapping]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you show the unwrapping you did? one thing I can think of could be that it's mapping only a very small part of the sphere

Comment: the strength of 500 kills the detail on the map. Try looking into the the experimental features to displace your mesh

Comment: Setting the Image texture to non-color should help to.. But what Sidar says, search for micro displacement and adaptive subsurf.

Comment: Enable smooth shading.

Comment: @LukeS I have added the UV wrapping as an image.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.
The subsurf for rendering was accidentally switched off when baking the bump map.

Thanks for all your inputs!